# Convert CSV file in shapefile with pyshp/shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, csv, pyshp

I'm trying to convert a `file.csv` to a `file.shp` through the pyshp / shapefile module.
The content of the CSV is:

```
Lon,Lat,Vel,Dir
15.9576198620869825,41.1791119428255143,9.3949995040893555,92.0000000000000000
15.9598119351079415,41.1791119428255143,9.3949995040893555,92.0000000000000000
15.9620040081288987,41.1791119428255143,..., ...
```

the code I wrote is as follows:

```
import csv
import shapefile as shp  

points = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
with open(csv_path + '.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     header = csvreader.fieldnames
     [points.field(field) for field in header]
     for row in csvreader:
        points.point((float(row['Lon'])),(float(row['Lat'])))
        points.record(*tuple([row[f] for f in header]))
points.save(r'path/to/output/file.shp')
```

I always used this code without problems, but I don't understand why in this case it return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 110, in <module>
    points = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapefile.py", line 1018, in __init__
    self.shp = self.__getFileObj(os.path.splitext(target)[0] + '.shp')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 98, in splitext
    return genericpath._splitext(p, sep, altsep, extsep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 99, in _splitext
    sepIndex = p.rfind(sep)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: Looks like `shapefile.Writer()` takes the path to the shapefile, not the type of shapefile.  `shapefile.POINT` is likely an integer "constant" representing that geometry type, hence the error complaining about an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using the features of ogr2ogr:

```
import gdal
import os
os.system('ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -a_srs EPSG:4326 '\
          '-oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lon -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lat '\
          '-oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO '\
          '/path/to/output/shapefile.shp '
          'path/to/input/file.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in pyshp version 2.0.0 (the version I was using which came out a coupt of days ago). I rolled back to version 1.2.12 and it's working again. More details for it at the link. It will be amended in the next rollout:

https://github.com/pytroll/pycoast/issues/17

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using the latest version of pyshp and without using GDAL:

replace

```
points = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
```

with

```
points = shp.Writer('your_shapefile_name_here', shapeType = shp.POINT)
```

and (you may not need this)

```
with open('testing.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
```

with

```
with open('testing.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
```

(I personally received an error asking me if I meant to read in text instead of read in binary);

and finally, delete

```
    points.save(r'path/to/output/file.shp')
```

since your points will be saved as they write, and the shapefile is already named ('your_shapefile_name_here') above.